# Layer colouring issue

Tags: color, layers, autocad

I created a dxf from a group of layers in QGIS, and brought this into AutoCad 2023 and saved as a DWG.  Every layer shows black on the model view but is red under layer properties.  When I try to change the colour of the layers they remain black.  Am I missing something obvious?[image]

Comment: Individual objects can have color overrides. So changing layer properties wont do any good in that case. Anyway, this might not be the best place to ask as autocad usage is generally not graphic design.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. This question doesn't seem to be about graphic design or graphic design software. So I'm voting to close it as off topic. Sorry about that. There is a [GIS Stack Exhcange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) where you might get answers, or alternatively [Engineering Stack Exhcange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/) for AutoCAD questions.